# Can't access a struct from one contract in another contract through interfaces. Any help?

Tags: solidity, struct, interfaces

I am trying to use a struct defined in one contract in another with the ise of interfaces. But my test cases is giving an error,

```
AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with Amount cannot be more than the tokens available, but other exception was thrown: Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function
```

First Contract:

```
  function getLockup(uint32 _serialNo)
        public
        view
        returns (PLibrary.Lockup memory)
    {
        PLibrary.Lockup memory lockInfo = totalLockups[_serialNo];

        if (changeInAPR > 10000) {
            lockInfo.totalAPR += (changeInAPR - 10000);
            lockInfo.dailyRewardPercentage = uint128(
                (lockInfo.totalAPR * (10**8)) / (365 * 3 * 100)
            );
        } else if (changeInAPR < 10000) {
            lockInfo.totalAPR -= (10000 - changeInAPR);
            lockInfo.dailyRewardPercentage = uint128(
                (lockInfo.totalAPR * (10**8)) / (365 * 3 * 100)
            );
        }

        return lockInfo;
    }
```

Interface:

```
function getLockup(uint256 index)
    external
    view
    returns (PLibrary.Lockup memory);
```

Second Contract:

```
function unStake(address _currencyAddress, uint256 _amount)
        external
        override
        nonReentrant
    {
        PLibrary.UserStake storage userInfo = userMapping[msg.sender][
            _currencyAddress
        ];

        PLibrary.Lockup memory lockInfo = pCron.getLockup(
            userInfo.lockupSerial
        );  // Error here

        uint32 _timeStamp = uint32(block.timestamp);
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your first contract does not implement the interface. The function is defined as

```
function getLockup(uint32 _serialNo)
```

which has a different selector than

```
function getLockup(uint256 index)
```

Functions are identified by their 4 bytes selector: `keccak256('getLockup(uint256)')`. The parameter types change the signature, which is why your function cannot be found.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found this mistake after debugging the code again. It works well now.